# Given a set X of intervals $[a_j, b_j] \subset \mathbb{R}$, prove that there exists a point that is in each of the intervals.

Tags: real-analysis

I was given a task to prove the following:

> Given a set X which consists of intervals $[a_j, b_j] \subset \mathbb{R} $, such that any 2 intervals have the same point. Prove that there exists a point that is in each of the intervals.

I have constructed my own proof, but since I am a novice in mathematics, I do not know whether it is correct. Could you please check my proof?

> Let's take an interval M. We're given that any two intervals have the same point. Therefore, M shares the same point with each one of the intervals. Therefore, $\exists p \in \mathbb{R} : \forall [a_j, b_j] p \in [a_j, b_j]$.

Comment: If $X$ is a set of intervals (by the problem statement), what do you mean by "take *interval* X"? And also, what is $A$?

Comment: @Al.G. I  edited text. Thanks. for mentioning that.

Comment: Ok, that's better :). Now, in your statement "Therefore, M shares the same point with each of the intervals", you assume that this point is the same for all intervals, which is not necessarily true. For example, with two other intervals, $M_1$ and $M_2$, you  have $\exists p_1 \in M_1 \cap M$ and $\exists p_2 \in M_2 \cap M$, but you don't know whether $p_1 = p_2$, so you cannot conclude that $\exists p\in \mathbb R \, \forall I \in X: p\in I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You derive the existence of such a $p$ from your third sentence:

> Therefore, M shares the same point with each one of the intervals.

which does not directly follow from the problem statement that "Any two intervals contain a common point."

You know $\forall M, M' \in X: \exists p \in M \cap M'$.
You do **not** know that $\forall M \exists p \forall M': p \in M \cap M'$.

The difference is that this $p$ may vary, depending on the chosen $M$ and $M'$, while you assume it's the same for all $M'$ for a fixed $M$.

Instead, I'd suggest you to look at the problem this way: prove that the intersection of all intervals is not empty.

Now, *what is* the set $S = \bigcap_{M\in X} M$? How does it look like? It's an intersection of intervals, so it's either an interval itself, or the empty set. You want to prove the former, i.e. you <strike>know</strike>hope that it's of the form $[a, b]$.
Next, you should ask yourself: if it would be the case that $\bigcap_{M\in X} M = [a, b]$, what are $a$ and $b$?

When you find out (you can write in the comments) what they <strike>are</strike>should be, you're left to prove that in fact $a < b$, which goes quite easy by contradiction.